# action to spring mvc controller mapped at application root

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

My controller has a method mapped to application root:

```
  @RequestMapping(value= "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home(HttpSession session){
            session.invalidate();
            return "home";
        }
```

In my JSP I need to make a GET request to that mapping. I tried

```
<form action=""><input type="submit" value="logout"></form>
```

It doesn't work. Is it possible to do what I want or I really need to map to something more than "/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<form action="."><input type="submit" value="logout"></form>
```